# bring the output into single column from a table as vertical order

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

```
Name    Age     Type    City
Tom     20      life    null
tim     null    motor   UK
john    55      null    USA
```

I need Output as

```
Tom
20
life
Tim
motor
UK
John
55
USA
```

Comment: Does the table have any `unique` (or primary key) constraint?

Comment: Is the structure of the table fixed? Are the column names and types known beforehand? What type do you want in the output? Does the order of the values in the output matter?

Comment: except null all records must come in vertical order

Comment: I mean "order" in terms of sorting. In your output, values from the first row are shown first, followed by values from the second and then the third row, and all values are taken from left to right. Is that order required? If so, please note that there should be a column in your original table to define the required order.

Comment: ya like that manner only

Comment: Investigate `UNPIVOT`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026236/sql-server-columns-to-rows).
You can achieve this using `CROSS APPLY` with `UNION ALL`:

```
select 
 c.x
from [mytable]
cross apply
(
 select [Name] union all
 select CAST([Age] as varchar) union all --all the columns must be of the same type
 select [Type] union all
 select [City] 
) c (x)
where x is not null ;
```

As pointed out by @Andriy M it could be also written like this:

```
select x
from [mytable]
cross apply
(VALUES ([Name]), (CAST([Age] as varchar)), ([Type]), ([City]))  c(x) -- parentheses are required
WHERE x IS NOT NULL
```

For more detail see [here](http://sqlstudies.com/2013/04/01/unpivot-a-table-using-cross-apply/).

The above query does not guarrantee any particular order of records in the resultset - to get a particular order of records in a resultset it is allways necessary to use the `ORDER BY` clause.

Comment: As this is SQL Server 2008 R2, they could also use VALUES: `CROSS APPLY (VALUES (Name), (CAST(Age AS varchar(10)), ...) AS c (x)`. The problem is, the order wouldn't be guaranteed either way.

Answer (score 2):

The issue here is mostly order. Otherwise you could just do `SELECT Name FROM Table UNION ALL SELECT Age...`

So let's assign some values to order by:

```
--This order is arbitrary, and will order the rows in whatever order they come.
WITH NumberedRows AS
(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS rownum
 FROM Table
)
--Now do a union all with things to column numbers too. Alias the first set, and cast Age to a string
, Unioned AS
(SELECT rownum, Name as Value, 1 as ColOrder
 FROM NumberedRows
 UNION ALL
 SELECT rownum, CAST(Age AS VARCHAR(3)), 2 as ColOrder
 FROM NumberedRows
 UNION ALL
 SELECT rownum, [Type], 3 as ColOrder
 FROM NumberedRows
 UNION ALL
 SELECT rownum, City, 4 as ColOrder
 FROM NumberedRows
)
--Now strip the nulls and extra columns, and order
SELECT Value
FROM Unioned
WHERE Value IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY rownum, ColOrder;
```